# Multiple Inheritance ER Model

Tags: database, entity-relationship

In enhanced ER modelling subclass inheriting from more than 1 super-class is called Multiple Inheritance!

Please explain me this using a suitable example. Thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Multiple inheritance and mapping to relational schema